# JFace TableViewer draw a rectangle on cell like Excel

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am trying to achieve a Excel like functionality in a `TableViewer` to draw a rectangle in a highlighted cell. Below is the code snippet doing this work, but it is not working completely as only left and top edges are getting drawn and I am not able to understand why the bottom and right edges are getting missed!

Code snippet :

```
private void markFocusedCell(Event event, ViewerCell cell) {
        GC gc = event.gc;

        event.gc.setAlpha(200);
        event.gc.setForeground(event.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

        Rectangle rect = cell.getBounds();

        gc.drawRectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
        event.gc.setForeground(event.display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));

        event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
    }
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it, the drawn rectangle is as big as the cell, and therefore, it does not fit inside it.

I would try drawing in the following way:

`gc.drawRectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width-1, rect.height-1);`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to draw the bottom and right lines 1 pixel up / to the right:

```
gc.drawRectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width - 1, rect.height - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want more Excel like functionality, why don't you use 
[NatTable](https://eclipse.org/nattable/)?